# How to make all non static parts of a NodeJS SailsJS web app load via ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

I am new to SailsJS and so with NodeJS and I was following a tutorial on building a simple web app using it.

Now, my question is, how could I render the views (except the template) via Ajax? I want it to work just like the official SailsJS website (http://sailsjs.org)

and this is what my web app looks like:
http://activityoverlord.herokuapp.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official SailsJS website (http://sailsjs.org) doesn't make any AJAX requests to get a view for another page. What it really does is loads a (relatively) huge JavaScript file with precompiled JST-templates (http://sailsjs.org/jst.js) whenever the first page of the site is accessed and then just pastes necessary template whenever an internal link is followed.

The view templates were initially each in its own HTML file, and they were precompiled, probably, with [Grunt JST plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jst).

That said, nobody forbids you to load views via AJAX: just disable layout for your controller/action and access it with jQuery's `$.get()` or something like that.